# How do you remove the comma from a number?

Tags: javascript

I have script that works fine until the shopping cart hits $1,000 or more then stops working. So I basically need a code that will remove the comma from this statement below when the cart hits 1,000 or more:

```
var cartValue = '##CARTSUBTOTAL##'
```

`##CARTSUBTOTAL##` pulls the subtotal amount. Everything works fine if the total is under 999.99. When it hits $1,000.00 the script doesn't work. The part that won't work is:

```
+ Math.abs(2500 - cartValue).toFixed(2) +
```

I'm assuming the comma is messing up the math calculation when 2500-1,000 comes up.

The calculation evaluates to `NaN`.

Comment: I think you would rather want to get the amount in the correct format to start with than start playing around with strings

Comment: ##CARTSUBTOTAL## pulls the subtotal amount. Everything works fine if the total is under 999.99. When it hits $1,000.00 the script doesn't work. The part that won't work is; "+Math.abs(2500-cartValue).toFixed(2)+". I'm assuming the comma is messing up the math calculation when 2500-1,000 comes up.

Comment: @Bacardi, please add your last comment to your question body. Another improvement of the question would be to specify exactly which facility "pools" the subtotal amount to your script. Usually, you should provide us with a complete example of your code and tell which result do you get, and which do you expect.

Comment: You need something like `cartValue = cartValue.replace(/,/g,'')` after the assignment and before the `Math.abs` is evaluated.

Comment: Holy cow I figured it out with that Rob. You're the man thanks! I just starting learning today haha

Answer (score 2):

You can try using replace. The g in the function will find all instances of "," in the string and replace it with nothing.

```
var mystring = "1,000,000";
mystring = mystring.replace(/,/g,"")
console.log(mystring);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you do something like this then,

Altough the dollar sign is not included:

```
var num="1,000,00";
var getin=true;
var concatenate="";
for (var i=0; i<num.length; i++)
{
    if (num[i]=="," && getin){ getin=false;continue;}
    concatenate+=num[i];
}
alert(parseInt(concatenate));
```

It would also work for values greater then 9999 ect..

Answer (score 0):

Or you can just use:

```
var num = "1,000.00";
var noComma = num.replace(',','');
```

I hope that will help you

Comment: Ok but how do I use that with this: var cartValue = '##CARTSUBTOTAL##'

Comment: Sorry I'm completely new to Javascript haha

Comment: Is your cartValue equal the string "##CARTSUBTOTAL##" or it's a floating number? In the second case: cartValue = cartValue.replace(',','');

Comment: Maybe you just want: Math.abs(2500 - 1* cartValue.replace(',','')).toFixed(2);